# Why is the existence of the scope checked in Laravel Eloquent Builder albeit it was only cloned

Tags: php, laravel

Digging through the code of Laravel I explored code I do not fully understand.

```
public function applyScopes()
{
    if (! $this->scopes) {
        return $this;
    }
    $builder = clone $this;
    foreach ($this->scopes as $identifier => $scope) {
        if (! isset($builder->scopes[$identifier])) {
            continue;
        }
        $builder->callScope(function (Builder $builder) use ($scope) {
            // If the scope is a Closure we will just go ahead and call the scope with the
            // builder instance. The "callScope" method will properly group the clauses
            // that are added to this query so "where" clauses maintain proper logic.
            if ($scope instanceof Closure) {
                $scope($builder);
            }
            // If the scope is a scope object, we will call the apply method on this scope
            // passing in the builder and the model instance. After we run all of these
            // scopes we will return back the builder instance to the outside caller.
            if ($scope instanceof Scope) {
                $scope->apply($builder, $this->getModel());
            }
        });
    }
    return $builder;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/56a58e0fa3d845bb992d7c64ac9bb6d0c24b745a/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L901-L932)

The `this` object is cloned. The documentation says, that every property are shallow cloned which means all references to other objects are still there. The magic `__clone` only makes an exception for the `query` property which is not used here.

Why is it necessary to make this check:

```
    if (! isset($builder->scopes[$identifier])) {
        continue;
    }
```

Shouldnt `this` and `builder` have the same scopes defined (even the same reference to them)? Why even bother checking it then?

And why is `this->getModel()` called instead of `builder.getModel()`? Only because it is shorter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this Laravel uses git you can use [git blame](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/1fe2ef87ca0a8834a01019fa88e4b8546aa208d7) to get the general idea what the code does and why, after checking out git blame you can see that there was an [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19282) linked to the commit.

The code was added as a fix for issue 19282, and it allows user to **remove a global scope using another global scope**.

Use-case:

> Let's say we have products which can be soft-deleted.
>   Normal users can manipulate only existing products, but users with elevated privileges can manipulate also deleted ones. Adding a global scope which removes SoftDeletingScope under some condition does not work - the SoftDeletingScope is removed but is also applied right after.

Comment: Ah, so it is for the case, that callScope removed a scope from the builder and might not be available anymore?

Comment: Here is usecase + implementation https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19657 as you can see KKSzymanowski wanted to remove in his example SoftDeletes scope with his own anonymous global scope. I hope it makes sense. Good luck! :)